# Задать фон с помощью JavaScript для каждой нечетной секции

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Доброй ночи. Появилась идея задать свой фон для каждой нечетной `<section>` находящейся в блоке `.main`

html выглядит примерно так:

```
    <div class="main">
      <section></section>
      <section></section>...и т.д.
```

Количество секций которое должно получаться в итоге я не знаю, начал с 4х.
Картинки лежат в папке ../img/bg/(их там с запасом). Пронумерованы по принципу 1.jpg и тд

Вот JS код:

```
$(document).ready(function bgi() {
    //считаем количество нечетных секций в блоке main
    var sectNum = $(".main:nth-child(odd)").length;
    //крутим цикл столько раз сколько у нас секций
    for (i=0; i<=sectNum-1; i++) {
        var j = i+1;            
        //путь до фона должен иметь вид N.jpg
        var img = ("url(../img/bg/" + (i+1) + ".jpg)");
        //применяем фон для секции
        $(".main:nth-child(odd)[j]").css("backgroundImage", img)
    }
});
```

Путем проб и ошибок добился того, что консоль не кричит об ошибках в JS, но всё же код не работает.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: фоны третьего и пятого элемента bg3.jpg и bg5.jpg или bg2.jpg и bg3.jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если правильно понял проблему тогда решение следующее:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var sectNum = $(".main section").length; // берём количество всех section
    for (i=1; i <= sectNum; i++) {
        if(i % 2 !== 0) { // работаем только с нечетными
            $(".main section:nth-of-type("+i+")").css("background-image", "url(../img/bg/"+i+".jpg)");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Обращаться часто к DOM - грех, браузер анафеме предаст.

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.main section:nth-child(odd)')).forEach(e => {
    /** {HTMLElement} e Один из нечётных элементов section */
    /** {Number} pos Позиция этого элемента в списке */
    let pos = getPosInt(e);
    
    // Замени эту строку на стили и заработает
    e.innerHTML = 'I want to load "../img/bg/' + getPosInt(e) + '.jpg"!';
    // e.style.background = 'url("../img/bg/' + getPosInt(e) + '.jpg")';
});

function getPosInt(e){
    let count = 0;
    while(e.previousElementSibling !== null){
     e = e.previousElementSibling;
        count++;
    }
    
    return ++count;
}
```

```css
section{
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .3);
}
section:nth-child(odd){
    background: rgba(0, 255, 0, .3);
}
```

```html
<div class='main'>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
    <section></section>
</div>
```

Comment: Функция `getPosInt()` явно лишняя. Коллбэк для метода `forEach` принимает в качестве второго аргумента принимает индекс элемента в массиве.

Comment: @tutankhamun Индекс элемента массива и позиция в DOM относительно предка - вещи разные.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    // перебираем все <section>
    $('.main section').each(function(ix) {
        // индекс фона нумеруется с 1
        var bgIx = ix + 1;
        // если индекс нечетный
        if (bgIx & 1) {
            // применяем соответствующий фон
            $(this).css({
                backgroundImage', 'url("../img/bg' + bgIx + '.jpg)'
            });
        }
    });
});
```